# How can I mock the return value of a function to be a string, then mock out the return value of an attribute of that function?

Tags: python, mocking, magicmock

So I am working with the below basic function:

```
def whatever(..): 
    for input_file in files:
        compressed_file = Path(input_file)
    if not compressed_file.name.replace('test_', '').startswith(COMPRESSED_FILE_PREFIX):
        continue
```

So I mock the `Path` function like this:

```
@mock.patch('path_to_Path_function.Path')
def test_choose_MFII_files(mock_Path):
    mock_Path.return_value = 'files/exchange' 
    mock_Path.name.return_value = 'whatever'
```

Now when I run this, I get an error saying

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'
```

I can see why I get this error, because `mock_Path.return_value` is set to a string!
But how can I set `mockPath.name.return_value` to whatever; I just want to mock it out.

I think using `MagicMock()` somehow would work but I'm not sure how. Any help would be great!

Comment: Your function returns `None` at the moment so there is nothing to mock in the return.

Comment: You are testing code that expects the return value to have a `.name` attribute; strings don't have such an attribute; therefore, you cannot mock the return value with a string. Instead, mock it with an object that has the needed attribute; since you want that attribute to be a string, set it to a string. This is about understanding the logic behind the test conditions, not about how to use the mock framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want:

```
@mock.patch('path_to_Path_function.Path')
def test_choose_MFII_files(mock_Path):
    mock_Path.return_value.name = 'whatever'
    path_to_Path_function.whatever(...)
```

`mock_Path`'s return value (which defaults to another mock object) corresponds to `compressed_file` in the function under test, so the thing you want to set to a string is the `name` attribute of that object.

If you wanted to write it a little more verbosely to make the nesting more obvious it might look like:

```
@mock.patch('path_to_Path_function.Path')
def test_choose_MFII_files(mock_path_cls):
    mock_path_obj = mock_path_cls()
    mock_path_obj.name = 'whatever'
    path_to_Path_function.whatever(...)
```